# Can't get three.js to run locally

Tags: three.js

I am struggling to host three.js on my computer. I installed node and read through some other articles here that recommended trying to do the CDN install method but had no luck. They also recommended putting in the script tag "type= module" but I **want a separate JS file.** The code runs fine within the HTML  tag but not in its own file.

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.157.0/build/three.module.js';

const scene= new Three.Scene()
console.log(scene)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Code snippet error][image: Console error message]

Comment: The error message and warning you have shared as a screenshot is not the one you see locally. The problem is that stackoverflow does not support ES6 imports in their live examples yet. So I suggest you looking for 404 errors first. I could imagine the path `/main.js` isn't correct.

Comment: If you want to run it truly locally (not the Stack Overflow snippet), you'll need some kind of web server to host your HTML/JavaScript. If you're already using Node, there are several very easy to use micro servers available that can do exactly that. Once you've started your server, it should give you a link to where you need to point your browser to see your files in action.